# Image carousel not showing correctly on different browsers

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, display

Here I am using Flickity (from Metafizzy plugins) and it happens something weird with the carousel. It is a full-width carousel. I didn't edit anything in the carousel's required js and css files.
I am not using any css framework, only jquery, font-awesome and a lightbox.

If I am trying to see the page on Firefox via the localhost (as I always do), I can see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpBT1.jpg) (the images are supposed to be 350px height).
THEN I just press F12 to open inspector and the carousel is showing properly.
If I refresh the page using F5, same displaying issue..
But if I just click on logo name to load index.php, the carousel is still showing properly.

If I resize the window, the carousel displays correctly.

Same issue on google Chrome.

I also checked on Microsoft Edge and the carousel is always displaying correctly.

**Here is the HTML for the carousel**

```
    <div class="row" id="carousel">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="main-carousel">
              <div class="carousel-cell"><a href="img/couture/001.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="img/couture/001.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
              <div class="carousel-cell"><a href="img/couture/002.jpg" data-lightbox="image-2"><img src="img/couture/002.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
              <div class="carousel-cell"><a href="img/couture/003.jpg" data-lightbox="image-3"><img src="img/couture/003.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
              <div class="carousel-cell"><a href="img/couture/004.jpg" data-lightbox="image-4"><img src="img/couture/004.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
              <div class="carousel-cell"><a href="img/couture/005.jpg" data-lightbox="image-5"><img src="img/couture/005.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
              <div class="carousel-cell"><a href="img/couture/006.jpg" data-lightbox="image-6"><img src="img/couture/006.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
              <div class="carousel-cell"><a href="img/couture/007.jpg" data-lightbox="image-7"><img src="img/couture/007.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**And the script that come with it**

```
$('.main-carousel').flickity({
  cellAlign: 'left',
  contain: true,
  freeScroll: true,
  pageDots: false,
  wrapAround: true,
  autoPlay: 2500
});
```

**CSS**

```
#carousel{
    margin-top: 115px;
}

.main-carousel img{
    max-height: 350px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    #carousel{
        margin-top: 223px;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your `.main-carousel img` the rows:

```
-moz-max-height: 350px;
-moz-min-height: 350px;
```

Comment: When you open this in Firefox, does the width of the image is being displayed wrong too, or is it only the height?

Comment: Only height.. you can see it better here https://i.imgur.com/zmcqowa.png

Comment: Hm, @sptaule , in the inspector I see that the height of flickity-viewport is set to 18px, in the style atribute of the tag in html. I do not perfectly know this plug-in, but it may be the issue.

Comment: If I press Ctrl Shift M to get adaptive view and change width or height of the window, the carousel displays correctly

Comment: I added min-height: 350px; to .flickity-viewport but it still shows 18px height ! and the slider isn't working (autoplay, next and previous buttons...) : https://i.imgur.com/txiYhEt.jpg

Comment: min-height and max-height are used only for pictures, for flickity-viewport add "height" and do it directly in html not in css file, because atribute style styles have higher priority than styles from css files. So in html, in atribute style where you see 18px just place 350px.

Comment: Ok so after adding `.flickity-viewport{ height: 350px !important; }`  it has now the correct height but slider and images positionning are wrong, arrows do nothing... https://i.imgur.com/JcULxv0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.
The script was running before the page was completely loaded so I added this as an external function :

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.main-carousel').flickity({
      cellAlign: 'left',
      contain: true,
      freeScroll: true,
      pageDots: false,
      wrapAround: true,
      autoPlay: 2500
    });
});
```